# Different behavior in debug and release

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, undefined-behavior

In my custom ArrayProxy class. I have this test.

```
    "array_proxy_initializer_list"_test = [] {
        ArrayProxy<int> array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        expect(array.size() == 5);
        expect(array[0] == 1);
        expect(array[1] == 2);
        expect(array[2] == 3);
        expect(array[3] == 4);
        expect(array[4] == 5);
        LogInfo{array[0]};// in release log: 1166876000 
        LogInfo{array[1]};// in release log: 32758
    };
```

In debug mode. It work fine. And in release mode. It fails.

Here are my ArrayProxy class.

```
template<typename T>
    concept ContainerObject = requires(T t) {
        t.data();
        t.size();
    };

    template<typename T>
    class ArrayProxy
    {
    public:
        using value_type = T;

        constexpr ArrayProxy() : m_count(0), m_ptr(nullptr) {}
        constexpr ArrayProxy(std::nullptr_t) : m_count(0), m_ptr(nullptr) {}
        ArrayProxy(const T& value) : m_count(1), m_ptr(&value) {}
        ArrayProxy(std::size_t count, const T* ptr) : m_count(count), m_ptr(ptr) {}
        ArrayProxy(const std::initializer_list<T>& args) : m_count(args.size()), m_ptr(args.begin()) {}
        ArrayProxy(ContainerObject auto container) : m_count(container.size()), m_ptr(container.data()) {}

        template<std::size_t N>
        ArrayProxy(const T (&ptr)[N]) : m_count(N), m_ptr(ptr) {};

        const T& operator[](int i) const
        {
            return m_ptr[i];
        }

        std::size_t size() const
        {
            return m_count;
        }

        const T* data() const
        {
            return m_ptr;
        }

    private:
        const T*    m_ptr;
        std::size_t m_count;
    };
```

In my debug. I find a interesting behavior.

If I swap the order of m_*ptr and m*_count.

```
    private:
        std::size_t m_count;
        const T*    m_ptr;
    };
```

In both debug and release mode. It works fine.
I don't know why, Is there a ub in my code?

compile on msvc 2022 and c++20.

Comment: You initialize with a temporary, so you have dangling pointer.

Comment: I suggest to add `ArrayProxy(const std::initializer_list<T>&&) = delete` to avoid that issue.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. Because I don't know the memory mechanism of std::initializer_list. I want to know how ArrayProxy(const std::initializer_list<T>&&) = delete solved this issue.

Comment: That deleted constructor would produce a compilation error with your usage, (so avoid misusage of the interface and your runtime UB).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list: "The underlying array is a temporary array ..."

Comment: As to the "memory mechanism" of `std::initializer_list` ..... essentially it is a wrapper for a temporarily constructed array that is constructed in the calling statement (i.e. its lifetime commences just before being passed to the called function, and ends [on completion of the calling statement] immediately after the function returns).  So, if the function keeps any references/pointers to elements of that array, those references/pointers are dangling when the function returns.

Comment: In what way does your class differ from std::vector already offers

Comment: The risk of `ArrayProxy(const T& value) : m_count(1), m_ptr(&value) {}` storing a dangling pointer is huge.

Comment: This class is to pass some array to function. like void ```foo(const ArrayProxy<Item>&);```. It like std::span, but std::span can not construct by single value. This class is from vulkan-hpp. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/f25639bd17e650fcaab85667f280c8c20745b21e/snippets/ArrayProxy.hpp#L2. I want to write this with concept wo my proj. But I encounter with this issue today.

Comment: This class is designed to store temporary or non-temporary value. In some c-like api, it is useful. According to the cppreference, it seems like vulkan-hpp use it in a wrong way…@Jarod42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Peter. I know how to test this class. The std::initializer_list's life time if from function's call to return.

This class is used to wrap some c api like`void c_api(int* data, int size);`.
Use this class is friendly with modern cpp containers.

For example.

```cpp
void c_api_wrapped(const ArrayProxy<int>& arr)
{
    c_api(arr.data(), arr.size());
}

void test()
{
    c_api_wrapped(1);
    c_api_wrapped({1,2,3});
    std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3};
    c_api_wrapped(arr);
}
```

It is friendly for these temporary value called.

But my use-case is in a wrong way. This class can only use in function's param.

If I use this as a variable in other way. The std::initializer_list would be destroyed.

So I should change my test to:

```
void test_array_proxy(const rain::ArrayProxy<int>& arr, const std::vector<int>& ground_truth)
{
    boost::ut::expect(arr.size() == ground_truth.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    {
        boost::ut::expect(arr[i] == ground_truth[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    "array_proxy_initializer_list"_test = [] {
        std::vector<int> ground_truth = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        test_array_proxy({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, ground_truth);
    };
}
```

It will work fine and it show this class's usage.

As I mentioned this class is from vulkan-hpp. The vulkan-hpp also provided a `ArrayProxyNoTemporaries" to prevent these situation.

Thanks for your help!